# netsh advfirewall port range

Tags: windows, powershell, admin, netsh

I am trying to open out a few ports.
The following is the command I came up with which does work on a few machines and does not work in a few(Win 7).

`netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="open_40000_50000" dir=in localport=40000-50000 protocol=UDP action=allow`

For some reason a few machines give me the following error. Any idea as to what is wrong with the command?

```
C:\Program Files\ICW\home\Administrator>netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="open_40000_50000" dir=in localport=40000-50000 protocol=UDP action=allow

netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="open_40000_50000" dir=in localport=40000-50000 protocol=UDP action=allow

        An invalid port value was specified.

        Usage: add rule name=<string>
              dir=in|out
              action=allow|block|bypass
              [program=<program path>]
              [service=<service short name>|any]
              [description=<string>]
              [enable=yes|no (default=yes)]
              [profile=public|private|domain|any[,...]]
              [localip=any|<IPv4 address>|<IPv6 address>|<subnet>|<range>|<list>]
              [remoteip=any|localsubnet|dns|dhcp|wins|defaultgateway|
                 <IPv4 address>|<IPv6 address>|<subnet>|<range>|<list>]
              [localport=0-65535|RPC|RPC-EPMap|any[,...] (default=any)]
              [remoteport=0-65535|any[,...] (default=any)]
              [protocol=0-255|icmpv4|icmpv6|icmpv4:type,code|icmpv6:type,code|
                 tcp|udp|any (default=any)]
              [interfacetype=wireless|lan|ras|any]
              [rmtcomputergrp=<SDDL string>]
              [rmtusrgrp=<SDDL string>]
              [edge=yes|no (default=no)]
              [security=authenticate|authenc|notrequired (default=notrequired)]
```

Did search through a few forums. The only thing that worked was to specify individual ports instead of a port range which would take a very long time.
http://eedle.com/2009/02/02/open-a-range-of-ports-on-windows-firewall/

Comment: FYI. It fails only on 32 bit win 7. Fine on 64 bit machines.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a problem with the SP level of the Win7 machine (if only on Win7)
If you are having problems on Windows 2008 - port ranges are not supported (only on R2 and above).

From this [technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd734783%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) article:

there is a "NOTE" under the localport property description:

> "Port ranges are supported only on computers that are running Windows
> 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2."

Since 2008 R2 is x64 only, there may also be some limit on the x32 version of Win7 (e.g. it was based off the 2008 code base (instead of R2) to begin with, which doesn't support ranges)

Given those constraints, I'd look into the update level of the problem Windows machines to see if they are missing an update.

You might also try using smaller ranges of ports (e.g. less than 100 at a time)